# Angular: Create bootstrap like navbar using material2

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-material

I was going through `material2` docs to find out the details of how to create a nav-bar like the one `bootstrap` offers, but could not find. Could any one please share the documentation for creating `navbar` using `material2`? My bootstrap sample code is as follows. I want to create this navbar that automatically converts to hamburger on mobile layout. Thought of using `<mat-toolbar>`, but that does not renders as hamburger on mobile layout. Any idea how to get that complete functionality in Angular Material? The demo version of this bootstrap template is available here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/trybs_theme_me_complete.htm.

[image]

Bootstrap Code:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">WHO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WHAT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WHERE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you share the material code that you tried? if you can create a plunker it will help us

Comment: @Aravind I am not quite sure which component of material is basically synonymous to navbar. That's my main question. Thought of using toolbar, But that does not renders as hamburger on mobile layout. Any idea how to get that complete functionality in material?

Comment: you should be combining flex layout or bootstrap for responsiveness!

Comment: But the problem with using bootstrap is I have to include jQuery for the default actions to work. I dont want to include jQuery in Angular app that's why thought of moving to Material.

Comment: any drawbacks for not including `jQuery`? if so can you elaborate?

Comment: Let's not get into a flame war - he doesn't want to use jQuery in a TypeScript app and wants to investigate moving to material2 instead. Let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

`md-toolbar` is your friend (from [here](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/examples)).

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <button md-button routerLink="/"><md-icon>home</md-icon>{{title}}</button>
  <div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
      <button md-button routerLink="/products">Products</button>
      <button md-button routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</button>
  </div>
  <button md-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
     <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
  </button>
</md-toolbar>
<md-menu x-position="before" #menu="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item routerLink="/products">Products</button>
    <button md-menu-item routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</button>
    <button md-menu-item>Help</button>
</md-menu>
```

Don't forget to import the proper modules in your TypeScript code.

And if you want it sticky on the top - you can apply this:

```
.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But that does not renders as hamburger on mobile layout. Any idea how to get that complete functionality in material?

Comment: @Manu Updated with that. Haven't tested that it compiles - but gives you the basic idea for it.

Comment: Got error:  Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'md-menu-trigger-for' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

Comment: @Manu That's a missing import, probably the button or menu module.

Comment: Ok... Let me fix this one. Will surely update you if it works in some time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, I am late to update, I am still having the error: Can't bind to 'md-menu-trigger-for' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. Imported all modules. import { MatToolbarModule, MatMenuModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';

Comment: Did your add them under the import section of your AppModule as well?

Comment: yup, I later found that as per the latest release, the updated syntax is md->mat. Then it worked. However I found material2 way complex with no proper documentation and examples. Hence I decided to move out and using ngx-bootstrap instead. Thanks for all your help!